# Print if multiple columns in dataframe have specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to print "buy" and "too expensive" every time two columns have specific values.

I tried it with for, while, where loops....

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
'car' : ['BMW','BMW','VW','BMW','VW','VW'],
'price' : [10,5,10,5,5,10]
})
df.head()


 df=
    car price
 0  BMW   10
 1  BMW    5
 2  VW    10
 3  BMW    5
 4  VW     5
 5  VW    10
```

I want to only 3 prints in total which is why I have used a while loop. The count variable increases and at some point it will stop:

```
count=0
while 3-count>0:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if ( (df[['car']]=='BMW') & (df[['price']]==5)  ):
            print('hello')
            count +=1
        elif ( (df[['car']]=='VW') & (df[['price']]==10)  ):
            print('too expensive')
            count +=1
```

This is my error message:

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Your goal is probably not to print `hello`, but to do something when your conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the scalar values returned by iterrows instead of your df.filters.

If you just print the interrows, you get the following:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print('car', row[0], 'price', row[1])

car BMW price 10
car BMW price 5
car VW price 10
car BMW price 5
car VW price 5
car VW price 10
```

Using this we can get your solution below.

```
count=0
while 3-count>0:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if ( (row[0]=='BMW') & (row[1]==5)  ):
            print('buy')
            count +=1
        elif ( (row[0]=='VW') & (row[1]==10)  ):
            print('too expensive')
            count +=1

buy
too expensive
buy
too expensive
```

Comment: The reason I asked OP what he wants to do is to show him a vectorized solution from `pandas`. Now we still dont know what he exactly was trying to do.